# Carregar esses dados de forma mais rápida?

Tags: vb.net

Oi! O que eu gostaria é de exibir diretórios do Windows em um `ListBox`. No meu `Form` eu tenho um botão logo acima do `ListBox` que serve para voltar (diretório anterior) e o evento `SelectedIndexChanged` para pegar o caminho que está sendo clicado no `ListBox`.

Load:

```
  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load


    claForm.abcd("C:\...\Filmes")



End Sub
```

Button:

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    claForm.abcd(ClaForm.claTeste.PrevFolder1)
End Sub
```

SelectedIndexChanged

```
Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    claForm.abcd(ClaForm.claTeste.Subfolder1(ListBox1.SelectedItem))
End Sub
```

sub:

```
Dim claTeste As ClaListBoxOrder 'Indica o caminho atual mostrado no listbox. Nela contem: pasta anterior, pasta atual, pastas que estão dentro dela

Public Sub abcd(ByVal diretorio As String)

    ListBox1.Items.Clear()

    Dim path() As String = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(diretorio)
    If path.Length = 0 Then
        Return
    Else
        'Salva pasta que esta aberta no listbox

        Dim Dos As New DirectoryInfo(diretorio) 'pega o nome da pasta para aparecer no Listbox Ex: C:/.../nova pasta/ Coisas  == Coisas
        claTeste = New ClaListBoxOrder
        claTeste.Folder1 = diretorio
        claTeste.PrevFolder1 = Left(diretorio, Len(diretorio) - Len(Dos.Name) - 1)

        For Each folder In path
            'Algumas verificações para ver se a pasta será exibida
            If FileIO.FileSystem.GetFiles(folder, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories, "*.mp4", "*.avi", "*.wmv", "*.mkv").Count > 1 Then
                If FileIO.FileSystem.GetFiles(folder, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories, "*.mp4", "*.avi", "*.wmv", "*.mkv").Count > 0 Then

                    ' Carrega listbox com o nome da pasta 
                    Dim Di As New DirectoryInfo(folder)
                    ListBox1.Items.Add(Di.Name)
                    'dicionario nome que está no listbox, caminh dele
                    claTeste.Subfolder1.Add(Di.Name, folder)

                End If
                'Algumas verificações para ver se a pasta será exibida
            ElseIf FileIO.FileSystem.GetDirectories(folder, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly).Count > 0 Then 'pega pastas que tem outras pastas dentro com 1 arquivo de video só
                For Each files In FileIO.FileSystem.GetDirectories(folder, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories)
                    If FileIO.FileSystem.GetFiles(files, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories, "*.mp4", "*.avi", "*.wmv", "*.mkv").Count > 0 Then
                        If FileIO.FileSystem.GetFiles(folder, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories, "*.mp4", "*.avi", "*.wmv", "*.mkv").Count > 0 Then

                            ' Carrega listbox com o nome da pasta 
                            Dim Di As New DirectoryInfo(folder)
                            ListBox1.Items.Add(Di.Name)
                            'dicionario nome que está no listbox, caminh dele
                            claTeste.Subfolder1.Add(Di.Name, folder)

                        End If
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Esse código está funcionando do jeito que eu quero, mas ele é ondemand, ou seja sempre que eu clicar em algo no `Listbox` ele vai executar todas as verificações. O problema é que em alguns casos quando tem muitas pastas essa verificação demora. Eu tentei algumas formas de salvar os dados de todas as pastas e subpastas no programa para apenas requisitar depois, mas eu tive problemas com nomes repetidos de pastas, por exemplo o nome da pasta que está no `Listbox` é "Coisas", mas existem 2 caminhos de pastas diferentes que também tem o nome de "Cosias".

Ou seja o que eu quero é navegar pelos diretórios do Windows, exibindo apenas pastas no ListBox seguindo algumas regras. Se alguém poder ajudar com uma solução agradeço, só lembrando que não quero usar o `Treeview`.